# Apache Spark: comparison of map vs flatMap vs mapPartitions vs mapPartitionsWithIndex

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Apache Spark: comparison of map vs flatMap vs mapPartitions vs mapPartitionsWithIndex

Suggestions are welcome to improve our knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**map(func)**
What does it do?  Pass each element of the RDD through the supplied function; i.e. func

**flatMap(func)**
“Similar to map, but each input item can be mapped to 0 or more output items (so func should return a Seq rather than a single item).”

Compare flatMap to map in the following
[image]

**mapPartitions(func)**
Consider mapPartitions a tool for performance optimization. It won’t do much for you when running examples on your local machine compared to running across a cluster. It’s the same as map, but works with Spark RDD partitions. Remember the first D in RDD is “Distributed” – Resilient Distributed Datasets.  Or, put another way, you could say it is distributed over partitions.
[image]

**mapPartitionsWithIndex(func)**
Similar to mapPartitions, but also provides a function with an Int value to indicate the index position of the partition.
[image]

If we change the above example to use a parallelize’d list with 3 slices, our output changes significantly:
[image]