# Is it possible to drop Pyspark rows in map()?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

When performing a map function in Pyspark, I often want to drop data that fails the mapping function (in this example, converting to xml). I was wondering if there was a clean way to do this in the mapping step?

The obvious solution of returning blank still leaves an object in the RDD eg.

```python
### **** skip pyspark boilerplate ****

### function defs
from lxml import etree as ET
def return_valid_xml(one_line_input):
    try:
        root = ET.fromstring(one_line_input)
        return root
    except:
        return

### code that returns stuff for every line of input
valid_xml_data = someDataStrings.map(lambda x: return_valid_xml(x))
```

Coming up with a clever filter is a waste of my time, and a dumb filter like a try/except on `ET.fromstring()` `return true` is a waste of computational time, as I parse the XML twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent to scala.util.Try in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383275/what-is-the-equivalent-to-scala-util-try-in-pyspark)

Comment: You could try `flatMap`: return `[root]` on success and an empty list (`[]`) on failure.

Comment: Totally works (want to make it an answer?).  Why do you need to return a list though?  A `map` will successfully return `root`, but flatmap needs `[root]`.  Very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `flatMap` and return an empty list on failure:

```python
def return_valid_xml(one_line_input):
    try:
        root = ET.fromstring(one_line_input)
        return [root]
    except:
        return []

valid_xml_data = someDataStrings.flatMap(return_valid_xml)
```

Also you can just pass in `return_valid_xml`, instead of defining the `lambda` function.

Comment: Same question as before on why map will successfully return `root`, but flatmap needs `[root]`? :)

Comment: `flatMap` requires an iterable to be returned so that it can be flattened. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350722/what-is-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-and-a-good-use-case-for-each) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997900/apache-spark-comparison-of-map-vs-flatmap-vs-mappartitions-vs-mappartitionswith)